# Parsing Shopify JSON Webhook to CSV

Tags: json, parsing, csv, shopify

I need to parse specific fields from a Shopify Webhook that has been exported in JSON into CSV file.  One of the fields I need to target is the shipping address, how do I select "shipping_address" ==> "address1":"123 Shipping Street"?

```
{
"created_at":"2014-12-30T11:58:01-05:00",
"email":"jon@doe.ca",
"name":"#9999",
"subtotal_price":"229.94",
"taxes_included":false,
"order_number":1234,
"billing_address":{
    "address1":"123 Billing Street",
    "address2":null,
    "city":"Billtown",
    "company":"My Company",
    "country":"United States",
    "first_name":"Bob",
    "last_name":"Biller",
    "latitude":null,
    "longitude":null,
    "phone":"555-555-BILL",
    "province":"Kentucky",
    "zip":"K2P0B0",
    "name":"Bob Biller",
    "country_code":"US",
    "province_code":"KY"
    },
"shipping_address":{
    "address1":"123 Shipping Street",<!-- NEED THIS ADDRESS -->
    "address2":null,
    "city":"Shippington",
    "company":"Shipping Company",
    "country":"United States",
    "first_name":"Steve",
    "last_name":"Shipper",
    "latitude":null,
    "longitude":null,
    "phone":"555-555-SHIP",
    "province":"Kentucky",
    "zip":"K2P0S0",
    "name":"Steve Shipper",
    "country_code":"US",
    "province_code":"KY"
},
"customer":{
    "accepts_marketing":false,
    "created_at":null,
    "email":"john@test.com",
    "first_name":"John",
    "id":null,
    "last_name":"Smith",
    "last_order_id":null,
    "multipass_identifier":null,
    "note":null,
    "orders_count":0,
    "state":"disabled",
    "total_spent":"0.00",
    "updated_at":null,
    "verified_email":true,
    "tags":"",
    "last_order_name":null,
    "default_address":{
        "address1":"123 Elm St.",
        "address2":null,
        "city":"Ottawa",
        "company":null,
        "country":"Canada",
        "first_name":null,
        "id":null,
        "last_name":null,
        "phone":"123-123-1234",
        "province":"Ontario",
        "zip":"K2H7A8",
        "name":"",
        "province_code":"ON",
        "country_code":"CA",
        "country_name":"Canada",
        "default":true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a way to get data json from a webhook:

```
class Data{
    private $arrayOrder = array();
    public function __construct(){
        $this->process();
    }

    private function process(){
        $order = $this->getContents();
        if(!$order){
            error_log('something failed');
            exit();
        }
        $this->arrayOrder = array(
            'email'=>$order->email,
            'billing_address_address1'=>$order->billing_address->address1,
            'shipping_address_address1'=>$order->shipping_address->address1,
            'customer'=>array(
                'first_name'=>$order->customer->first_name,
                'default_address'=>$order->customer->default_address->address1
            )
        );
        error_log(json_encode($this->arrayOrder));//to test
    }

    private function getContents(){
        $webhookContent = "";
        $webhookContent = file_get_contents("php://input");
        if($webhookContent){
            $data = json_decode($webhookContent);
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
$csv = new Data();
```

to create a csv, use the manual example to put csv :http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON parser of course. The most obvious answer is always the one I go with. Since JSON can be directly interpreted with Javascript, your scripting language of choice could be Javascript to do this! If you cannot for some reason write your scripting code in Javascript, almost all other scripting languages of note come with a JSON parse instruction. In Ruby for example, you simply do a

```
data = JSON.parse someJSON
```

and now you can play with **data**. By not telling the world your choice of scripting language in your question, or whether you are in client or server world, it is nearly impossible to help you out more. Lucky for you, JSON is just text as is your CSV file. So nothing is stopping you from parsing your JSON using a JSON parser or just plain old Javascript.

Comment: I'm in client world, trying to parse specific fields from the mass of info they provide so I can make a CSV to send to a warehouse and simultaneously send an e-mail with the same info formatted to send to a sales-person. So I'm thinking combining the javascript and PHP will be the best method. So when a new order is created by the webhook it is formatted via PHP and then sent as a csv and an e-mail. Right @David Lazar?

Comment: You are not in client world at all. Dealing with Webhooks means you are in server world. So write your App to listen to the Webook you want. You get handed JSON. Parse it and do whatever you need to do. PHP can parse JSON, create CSV files and send emails, so you are done. No need for Javascript at all.

Comment: Ok, first, this is what I'm using to catch the webhook,

`<?php
$webhookContent = "";

$webhook = fopen('php://input' , 'rb');
while (!feof($webhook)) {
    $webhookContent .= fread($webhook, 4096);
}
fclose($webhook);

error_log($webhookContent);
?>`

Is this the best way to do so.  Second, I'm very new to JSON, what's the best way to go about parsing it?  I see your answer but I'm not sure how to implement it.